# SSIS 2019 Red Checks Green Plus (+) signs - unable to edit/design view dtsx projects

Tags: ssis

All, I'm using VS Community 2019.  All of a sudden - out of nowhere - all of my .dtsx projects have red check marks or green plus signs next to them and I can't access them (right-click, design view) or even execute/run them.  When I click on a .dtsx package a code panel immediately opens with what appears to be XML code of some sort.

Here's a snippet of my solution explorer:

[image]

I've read on StackOverflow that these check marks mean a change has been made recently and that the solution is to click File\Source Control\Refresh status - Maybe I'm not following but that doesn't appear to be an option (I've done the tools\options\source control\visual studio team foundation...) but what I end up with is this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does your organization use GIT? I had a similar transition when we switched from TFS to GIT

Comment: @PausePause:  We recently obtained a new SQL server (local to our office).  Was working fine using TFS.  I did some windows updates recently - not sure what would have triggered this.  Any ideas on how to switch to GIT?

Comment: No doubt you'd be informed if your organization started a transition to git. If that can't be used to explain the cause then I'm not the one to help you further. Sorry. fwiw you can always try the safe option of repairing your instance of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track in the comments.  The checkmark is noting a changed file in source control, the + is an added file, the red circle dash are ignored folders.

The ssis extension has never been able to show these icons in the solution explorer.  You're looking at this from the folder explorer view in visual studio, but the solution is not opened up, so you have no access to the SSIS features.  Open the solution and everything will be happy again.